Is Rx Automatic Gain Control useful in such a situation?
This is referring to AGC before hitting the ADC, i.e. before any DSP
We have a situation where the signal of interest is always buried in noise by at least 10 dB nomatter how strong it is.
Is there any meaning or any use  for any variable analog  gain or automatic gain control before the ADC in this case?

Depends on what the "noise" is. Could you post further details on what the signal is, what the noise looks like, etc. For example if the SNR of the incoming signal is high, but the amplitude is only a tiny fraction of the ADC range, extra gain will likely help. If the SNR of the incoming signal is very poor, amplifying the signal wont make it better.

The signal of interest is 10 dB lower than thermal noise. Higher analog gain is good for NF and noise performance because it reduces the impact of ADC noise, but nevertheless we still have 10 dB difference between thermal noise and the signal of interest

What is the nature of the signal and of the noise?

Thermal noise and QAM signal


Is there any meaning or any use for any variable analog gain or
automatic gain control before the ADC in this case?

No because it will amplify noise the same way it amplifies the signal.
Your best bet is to try and filter-away the noise or, maybe if the wanted signal repeats itself in a known way, you can use DSP techniques to try and cancel some noise.
